# Drop Down Filter in Devexpress Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, devexpress

I want to filter rows by columns, so that i can choose multiple items in filter column dropdown (items in dropdown is preferable to be checkboxes). Can you show me an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, both the ASPxGridView/MVC GridView Extension do not support multi-select filter.

There is a request regarding this improvement:

[Pivot Like Multi Select Filter](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S90968.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Set the column's `OptionsFilter.FilterPopupMode` to CheckedList.

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q250696.aspx

Comment: settings.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.FieldName = "Name";
            column.Caption = "Name";

            column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.;
        }); column doesn't have FilterPopupMode property. please tell me where exactly place that

Comment: Is your answer about windows forms? I need this function in asp.net mvc